# How come my ExtJS 5 panel cannot resolve a show listener via it's VC? W/ Fiddle

Tags: javascript, extjs5

ExtJS 5.1.3 - I'm slightly baffled that a simple Panel cannot resolve its VC on 'show' event. The attached fiddle will work - it has a panel with VC. Click the button to see the VC correctly resolved.

If you un-comment the 'show' event however, the code will fail in the console because the function can't be found (Unable to dynamically resolve scope for "show" listener on mypanel-xxxx). Lots of my code works like this already, am I doing something stupid?

I've tried using add() instead of widget() in case it's some kind of MVC nesting issue but Ext just seeks the function in the wrong VC - the top-level VC applied to the viewport.

Any help very much appreciated. Thx

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kvd

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.TheController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias  : 'controller.thecontroller',

    doShowStuff : function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('SHOW STUFF!', 'yep, this works');
    },

    doOkStuff : function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('OK STUFF!', 'yep, this works');
    }
});

Ext.define('Admin.view.Panel.MyPanel', {
    extend     : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias      : 'widget.mypanel',
    autoRender : true,
    autoShow   : true,
    controller : 'thecontroller',
    width      : 200,
    height     : 200,
    html       : 'I am your panel',

    buttons : [
        { text : 'OK', handler : 'doOkStuff', scope : 'controller' }
    ],

    listeners : [
        // This listener causes an error
        //{ show : 'doShowStuff', scope : 'controller' },
    ]
});

Ext.widget('mypanel');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listeners: {
    // This listener causes an error
    show:{
        fn: 'doShowStuff',
        scope: 'controller'
    }
}
```

here's the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1l6s)

Comment: :facepalm: thanks I guess I assumed because the library was seeking a controller _at all_ that the listener config was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your listeners are misconfigured, they should be an object, not an array. Also, you should omit the scope, it will be automatically determined:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.Panel.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mypanel',
    autoShow: true,
    controller: 'thecontroller',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    html: 'I am your panel',

    buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: 'doOkStuff'
    }],

    listeners: {
        show: 'doShowStuff'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ET - @Mr.George answered first

Comment: Sure, but you should still remove the `scope`.